# If-Else Statements for multiple conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am currently having a hard time figuring out how to use multiple conditions for my if-else statements. I can do 1 condition at a time, but multiples are a problem for me. I'm not quite sure where to start with the multiple one as I'm using the HTML form stuff, and I'm not sure where to start with it as well. Any sample code is fine as I would like to learn rather than have people figure everything out for me.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+if+else+javascript

Comment: There are operators like AND(&&) , OR(||) , NOT(!) which can be used inside an if statement. Search about them.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's start from the beginning.

You agree that this code right here:

```
if (true)
    console.log('foo');
```

obviously prints out `'foo'` on your console, cause the condition is satisfied (i.e. is `true`).

Let's try something different now:

```
if (true && false)
    console.log('bar');
```

The `&&` in Javascript and most programming languages is the `and` operator, which evaluates to `true` only if both the conditions at its left and at its right are `true`. This means that the code above does **not** print out `'bar'`.

```
if (true || false)
     console.log('bla');
```

The `||` operator, on the other hand, is the `or` operator, which is `true` when one of the two conditions (or both) is `true`. In this case, `'bla'` is printed out on your console.
In the end, let's have a look at the `!` operator (`not`): if the condition that follows the operator is `true`, then it evaluates to `false`, and viceversa. So writing `if (!false)` equals `if (true)`. 

Now you can apply these simple rules to easily use multiple logical conditions in one `if` or `else` branch. Remember the precedence of the logical operators, i.e. which one you have to evaluate first if you have more than one, taking a look here: [Which Logic Operator Takes Precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157814/which-logic-operator-takes-precedence)