# Javascript multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a total beginner in Javascript and trying to edit an existing code.
My goal is to add multiple statements for when to show some graphics.

```
var unique1 = ['TRIGGER','d2','d3'];
var unique2 = ['d1'];
var unique3 = ['TRIGGER'];
var out1 = ['TRIGGER','d2','d2','d3'];
var out2 = ['d1'];
var out3 = ['TRIGGER'];

<div className="block">
    { out1.indexOf('TRIGGER') < 0 || unique1.length > 1 && (
        <div className="class1">
        </div>
    )}
    { out2.indexOf('TRIGGER') < 0 || unique2.length > 1 && (
        <div className="class2">
        </div>
    )}
    { out3.indexOf('TRIGGER') < 0 || unique3.length > 1 && (
        <div className="class3">
        </div>
    )}
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
<div className="block">
        <div className="class1">
        </div>
        <div className="class2">
        </div>
</div>
```

The output I get:

```
<div className="block">
        <div className="class1">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Logic Operator Takes Precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157814/which-logic-operator-takes-precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using parentheses like this:

```
{ (out1.indexOf('TRIGGER') < 0 || unique1.length > 1) && (
    <div className="class1">
    </div>
)}
```